# Double integral with minimum and maximum

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I compute the following integral:
$$\int_0^t\int_0^se^{u \land r-u\lor r}drdu$$
I know how to solve it when there is only one integral, but the double integral it is making it harder.

Comment: so is $u\wedge r = \min\{u,r\}$ and $u\vee r = \max\{u, r\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that $u \land r=\min\{u,r\}$ and $u\lor r = \max \{u,r\}$ we have two cases: $t>s$ or $t<S$. We define $f(u,r)=\frac{e^{\min\{u,r\}}}{e^{\max \{u,r\}}}$

First consider $t<s$ in this

$$\int_0^t\int_0^sf(u,r)drdu = \int_0^tdu\int_0^u \frac{e^r}{e^u}dr+\int_t^sdu\int_0^t \frac{e^r}{e^u}dr+\int_0^tdu\int_u^t \frac{e^u}{e^r}dr$$

Now if we consider $t>s$ the we have

$$\int_0^t\int_0^sf(u,r)drdu =\int_0^sdr\int_r^s \frac{e^r}{e^u}du+\int_0^sdr\int_0^r \frac{e^u}{e^r}du+\int_s^tdr\int_0^s \frac{e^u}{e^r}du$$

Now we have to evaluate each part. Here we go for the first one

$$\int_0^t\int_0^sf(u,r)drdu = \left(u+e^{-u}\right)\Bigl|_0^t + \left(1-e^t \right)e^{-u} \Bigl|_t^s+\left(u-e^ue^{-t}\right)\Bigl|_0^t=2t-2+2e^{-t} + (e^t-1)(e^{-t}-e^{-s})$$

For the second one we have

$$\int_0^t\int_0^sf(u,r)drdu = \left( -e^{-s}e^r-r\right)\Bigl|_0^s+\left(r+e^{-r} \right)\Bigl|_0^s+\left( e^{-r}(1-e^{s})\right)\Bigl|_s^t=(e^{-t}-e^{-s})(1-e^s)$$

In each integral you can change the order of integration, thus each first and second cases have 8 representations, but the answer must be the same.

Comment: $\int_s^tdr\int_0^s \frac{e^u}{e^r}du$ can u explain from where it comes from this integral? for the other two is like a one dimension integral

Comment: When $t>s$, the region of integration is a vertical rectangle in the $u-r$ plane (the vertical or $y$-axis is $r$ and horizontal or $x$-axis is $u$). If you draw the line $r=u$ (bisector of first quadrant) and the horizontal line $r=s$ you get three regions of integration. first region is below $r=u$ (triangle), the second region is above $r=u$ and below the line $r=s$ (triangle) and the third region is $r \in [s,t]$ and $u\in [0,s]$ (a rectangle). And here is another tip, I now realized that you can integrate with only two regions (below triangle and above trapezuidal)